Handle cors on DELETE request when passing an id
I'm just learning PHP/MySQL/Apache and trying to build a simple CRUD system with ReactJs, but I'm getting a cors error when passing a parameter to a DELETE method using fetch api and I can't figure it out.
I have the headers set up to allow cors origin and it works fine wit GET, POST and even DELETE without a parameter, but if I try to pass a parameter to the endpoint I get the cors error.
This works:
// JS
    fetch('http://localhost/crud/api/', {
      method: 'DELETE'
    })

// PHP
    public function handleDelete() {
        $db = new Database();
    
        $db->delete('usuarios', 21);
        $db->close();
    }

This doesn't:
//JS
fetch('http://localhost/crud/api/21', {
  method: 'DELETE'
})

// PHP
public function handleDelete() {
    $db = new Database();

    $uriSegments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $userId = $uriSegments[3];

    $db->delete('usuarios', $userId);
    $db->close();
}

Here it's my headers:
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.18.23:3000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');

The error:

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/crud/api/21' from origin
'http://192.168.18.23:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response
to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

